# Why wont this javascript run?

Tags: javascript

Someone created this code for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/kzFWa/

```
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("continue");
var counter = 60;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "<h3>or click here to continue in 60 seconds</h3>";
var id;

downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);

id = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if(counter < 0) {
        newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
        //newElement.innerHTML = "<a href="survey.php">Click Me To Continue</a>"
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        newElement.innerHTML = "<h3>or click here to continue in  " + counter.toString() + " seconds.</h3>";
    }
}, 1000);
```

However, if i change

```
newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
```

to

```
newElement.innerHTML = "<a href="survey.php">Click Me To Continue</a>"
```

the code will no longer run. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Look carefully at the quote characters in the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in:

```
newElement.innerHTML = "<a href="survey.php">Click Me To Continue</a>"
```

Double quotes can't be used within a double quoted string like that. Either escape or change to a combination of single quotes and double quotes:

```
newElement.innerHTML = '<a href="survey.php">Click Me To Continue</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in:

```
newElement.innerHTML = "<a href="survey.php">Click Me To Continue</a>"
```

Check the console and you'll see:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement    newElement.innerHTML = "Click Me To Continue"

so the code is not well formed, change it in:

```
newElement.innerHTML = "<a href='survey.php'>Click Me To Continue</a>";
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aY5PK/